# unload ajax when just closing a jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

i'm using this technique to load ajax into a jqueryui dialog

[load ajax dialog technique](http://8raystech.com/2011/06/28/how-to-dynamic-content-in-a-jquery-ui-dialog-by-loading-a-url-via-ajax)

it works fine

except for one this with my in my implementation

i have a calculation that i have put in the "complete" section...

```
options.complete = function(){
$("#quantity").bind("keyup",
                        function () {
                            var sum = 0;
                             price = $('#price').val();
                             qty =   $('#quantity').val();
                             sum = price*qty;

                            $('.total').text(sum);
 });        
}
```

That works fine on the first load every time. If i refresh it works like a charm.

I even tried the live method.

like this....

```
options.complete = function(){
 $("#quantity").live("keyup",
                        function () {
                            var sum = 0;
                             price = $('#price').val();
                             qty =   $('#quantity').val();
                             sum = price*qty;

                            $('.total').text(sum);
 });        
}
```

using the live method i get some interesting if i alert out a alert('here') at the top of the function.

each time i open and close the dialog and change the number in the quantity i get as many alerts as the amount of times that i have opened and closed the dialog

ie : open and close the dialog 3 times and i get 3 alerts....open it 5 times i get 5 alerts etc etc.

what i need to know is if there is a way to completely unload the ajax from the DOM with the jquery ui dialog beforeClose: method.

Thanks in advance.

Scott

```
oops forgot to put this in as well...

  "Cancel": function() {
            $(this).dialog("destroy");   
                            }
```

also does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a delegation method like live() , call it outside of other event handlers so it doesn't get bound repeatedly when your other events occur more than once. Live doesn't even need to be called inside $(document).ready() since it is delegated to the document.

Comment: thank you so much. that was it. that was driving me bat s*@t crazy

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to `destroy()` the dialog after closing it.

Comment: thanks for that but i've tried that too.... i have edited the post to reflect what is attached to the "Cancel" button.